# Error with xfrm.apply_to(model) in GDP, can't clone model with Set initialized

Tags: pyomo

I'm trying to solve a GDP in Pyomo, when I use the command xfrm.apply_to(model) I get the following error

```
ERROR: Unable to clone Pyomo component attribute. Component 'Agrupacion'
contains an uncopyable field '_init_values' (<class
'pyomo.core.base.set.TuplizeValuesInitializer'>).  Setting field to `None`
on new object

File "C:\Users\Samuel\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\var.py", line 455, in ub
ub = ub()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

My Agrupacion component is a Set that is initialized with the keys of a dictionary.

```
model.Agrupacion = Set(initialize = Agrupacion.keys())
```

I need this set to be initialised with these values.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

The error message says: *Setting field to 'None' on new object*

But I don't quite understand what it means. Does it mean that I should build an additional Set without initial values and relate it somehow to the other one, or does it simply mean that I should not set initial values to my Set Agrupacion?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question would be significant;y easier to answer if it included a (minimal) complete example of the problem.  In particular, `apply_to()` should be an in-place transformation and not require duplicating (cloning) the model.

The error you are seeing is because you are initializing the `Set` with `dict.keys()`.  That (Python) method returns a `dict_keys` object that is not deepcopyable (this is a known issue: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1510).  Since cloning a model is a specialized form of deepcopy, the `clone()` would usually fail.  However, Pyomo includes special "second chance" handling when a model fails to deepcopy cleanly where it will perform the deepcopy more manually and will remove component attributes that fail, replacing them with `None`.  The error you are seeing is warning you what just happened and giving you a hint where to look to resolve it.

The workaround is to initialize your `Set()` with a list instead of a `dict_keys` object, e.g.:

```py
model.I = Set(initialize=list(a_dict.keys()))
```

That said, the error about cloning and `_init_values` very likely unrelated to the exception about `'list' object is not callable`.  That is likely because you are somehow initializing a Var bounds to a list instead of a value, but it is really impossible to diagnose without a complete example.

Comment: Hi @jsiirola. Thanks for your help. I must say that your answer has solved both errors...

I initialized the Set with model.Agrupacion = Set(initialize = list(Agrupacion.keys())) and now it works correctly.

Regarding the other error, I had simply initialized the limits of my variables wrongly. I had used a list, which is an invalid form. Now I use a rule and everything is fine.

As for why I haven't uploaded an example model, I thought it was too long and I didn't know how to reduce it to show it in the forum.